# Adding game functionality (pause, resume) to multiple MVCs

Tags: objective-c, class, categories

I have a set of methods like so:

```
- (void)resumeGame;

- (void)resumeGameWithOverlay;

- (void)resumeGameOnLeavingBackground:(NSNotification *)notification;

- (void)pauseGame;

- (void)pauseGameOnEnteringBackground:(NSNotification *)notification;

- (void)endGame;
```

What I would like to do is be able to put them into a separate file so that these methods (which also need to access the MVC's instance variables) can be written only once but used in each different type of game I have, i.e. Marathon mode, Time Trial.

My first thought was simply adding them into another class, but then I found out about `Categories`. Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a while ago so forgive me, but it seems delegation is the best method, or good old `NSNotificationCenter`